# On my large (43"/4K) monitor, tmux resurrect always fails to reconstruct panes properly

Tags: tmux

All the windows in a session will be recovered when `tmux` is resurrected, but the panes within them are often misaligned.

I save at 80columns per terminal, so this gives me a session that, per window, is 5 panes wide with each subdivision containing 1-4 panes.  When I recover, many of the panes will be missing and the remainder will be strongly misaligned.  I spent several minutes adjusting things after every recovery and it's pretty annoying.

How I save it:

[image: screenshot]

and what I get back:

[image: ss2]

With 10+ windows, this is indeed a lot of panes total, but I don't think it's overloading my 32GB RAM system (Ubuntu 16.04/18.04), rather I suspect some tmux process is timing out before a given window can be redrawn properly.  This doesn't happen with smaller sessions.  Anyone know how I can get things working correctly for my case?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You can [edit] your question to add the screenshots using the button but they will appear as links- someone will edit them into your question for you :)